MySQL: How to get the last record which type equal to 3 including to fetch rest type rows?
I have a table and I want to fetch the lastest row which type = 3. based on the user_id also rest of the rows fetched which not type=3
Table - galleries
+----+----------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id  | type       |  photo   |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | 1          | img1.jpg |
|  2 | 2        | 1          | img2.jpg |
|  3 | 1        | 3          | img3.jpg |
|  4 | 1        | 2          | img4.jpg |
|  5 | 1        | 3          | img5.jpg |
|  6 | 3        | 1          | img6.jpg |
|  7 | 2        | 3          | img7.jpg |
+----+----------+------------+----------+

In above table, user_id=1 has more than 1 records which type=3. So in this case, I want to show the last record of this user using MySql Query.
My Output should be like:
+----+----------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id  | type       |  photo   |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | 1          | img1.jpg |
|  2 | 2        | 1          | img2.jpg |
|  4 | 1        | 2          | img4.jpg |
|  5 | 1        | 3          | img5.jpg |
|  6 | 3        | 1          | img6.jpg |
|  7 | 2        | 3          | img7.jpg |
+----+----------+------------+----------+

Please let me know how can I prepare a MySQL query for this?

Did you mean to post the same table for your expected output as for the input?

how do you define a record as "last"? in sql languages there is not such concept. Are you saying that you want the record with the highest ID between those that match the other criteria? Is Id an auto increment and unique field?

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to identify the rows that are duplicate, by PARTITION-ing the row numbering according to your requirements, then exclude them by filtering on the row number. I've used a derived table (i.e. select from () x), but you can achieve the same thing with a CTE or temp table.
First we create a table for the sample data:
create table userphoto (id int, user_id int, type int, photo varchar(10));
                        
insert into userphoto (id, user_id, type, photo)
values
(1, 1, 1, 'img1.jpg'),
(2, 2, 1, 'img2.jpg'),
(3, 1, 3, 'img3.jpg'),
(4, 1, 2, 'img4.jpg'),
(5, 1, 3, 'img5.jpg'),
(6, 3, 1, 'img6.jpg'),
(7, 2, 3, 'img7.jpg');

Then we select from it, rank and filter.
select id, user_id, type, photo
from
(
  select 
      row_number() over(partition by user_id, type order by id desc) as r,
      id, user_id, type, photo
  from userphoto 
) x
where x.r = 1
order by id;

And we see the results:



id
user_id
type
photo




1
1
1
img1.jpg


2
2
1
img2.jpg


4
1
2
img4.jpg


5
1
3
img5.jpg


6
3
1
img6.jpg


7
2
3
img7.jpg



Here's a dbfiddle demonstrating it.
BTW you will need to be running MYSQL v8.0 or greater for the ROW_NUMBER() function to be supported. If not, here's a stack overflow post discussing this change.

@Sahu CK glad to hear it! If my answer is correct, feel free to mark it as accepted :)

please up vote my question because i need at least 15 reputation to upvote your question.

Assuming that "last record" means the one with the highest Id you can do something like this:
SELECT MAX(id), user_id, type, photo 
FROM mytable
WHERE type=3
GROUP BY user_id

This query will filter only records that have type=3, group filtered records by user_id and for each group return only the record with the highest id. If this is the criteria to identify a record as last then the query should return what you are looking for
